# randomly select 3 numbers whose sum is 356 and each of these 3 is more than 30

Tags: python, python-2.7

please how can I randomly select 3 numbers whose sum is 356 and each of these 3 is more than 30?

So output should be for example [100, 34, 222]
(but not [1,5,350])

I would like to use random module to do this. thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random

def rnd_to_sum_with_min(desired_sum=356, numbers=3, minimum=31):
    selection = []
    for i in range(numbers-1):
        upper_limit = desired_sum - sum(selection) - (numbers - i) * minimum
        choice = random.randint(minimum, upper_limit)
        selection.append(choice)
    selection.append(desired_sum - sum(selection))
    return selection
```

This solution uses a function. This is so that parameters can be modified on-the-fly. This makes for a robust solution.

The method is to select the first N-1 numbers randomly, and determine the last number according to the difference to the desired sum. Each number is determined by first knowing the minimum value desired, and then calculating the upper limit of that number based on the desired sum, and what numbers have already been chosen, making sure to leave enough behind for the next n numbers.

I also wrote a recursive function just for fun (Which is faster):

```
def recursive_rnd_sum_by_n_with_min(_sum=356, _num=3, _min=31):
    def f(_sel=[]):
        left = _num - len(_sel) 
        so_far = sum(_sel)
        if left == 1:
            return _sel + [_sum - so_far]
        return f(_sel + [random.randint(_min, _sum - so_far - left * _min)])
    return f()
```

Comment: Inbar, dumping code with no explanation is asking a _lot_ of the OP. This would be far better if you also _explained_ what it's doing.

Comment: looks like the OP prefers the dump

Comment: That's the OP's right, of course, it _is_ their question after all so, if they just want to use it without understanding, that's fine. I for one would still like to see an explanation.

Comment: no, no, I just talked about speed between Inbar's and other solutions. I of course prefer to understand it, so please Inbar, post few words about it. thank you!

Comment: That's better, though I worry about people who write recursive functions "just for fun" :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I sometimes worry too!

Answer (score 6):

This question is rather subjective to the definition of random, and the distribution you wish to replicate.

The simplest solution:

- Choose a one random number, `rand1` : [30,296]
- Choose a second random number, `rand2` : [30, (326-Rand1)]
- Then the third cannot be random due to the constraint so calc via `356-(rand1+rand2)`

Comment: seriously this is simpler than mine?

Comment: there is no need for the exhaustive search using the while loop, i'm just being very pedantic about efficiency.

Comment: yah fair enough in this case it doesn't matter, my background is in HPC so  its just the way I automatically think about a problem!

Comment: Sorry, Sam, the `3)` at the end of `[30, (326-Rand1)]` confused me since I though it was part of it rather than the next point. Edited to clearly separate points, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Padraic So let's hope we don't want to run this a few hundred times then. Anyhow the *real* reason to prefer this over the other answer is that it is elegant and succinct and not just a code dump. In any case neither answer is perfect - I'd consider paxdiablo's answer  exemplary for how to answer the given question.

Comment: @Voo, for the quality of the question asked my answer is plenty good enough and if we ran it 100 times it would be around .3 of a second

Answer (score 5):

When choosing the first number, it needs to be `31` or more, and it must leave at least 62 on the table (assuming numbers don't have to be different) since the *other* two numbers will need to 31 or higher as well.

So it needs to come from the inclusive range `31..(356-31-31)`.

For the *second* number, it has to be `31` or more and it has to leave at least `31` on the table for the last number.

So its inclusive range will be `31..(356-31-first)`.

Then, the final number is simply `356-first-second` and there you have it.

There's already plenty of answers on SO about generating random numbers in a range in Python so I won't rehash that information, but the following code shows how to select the ranges for the two numbers and calculate the third:

```
import random
first = random.randint(31,356-31-31)
second = random.randint(31,356-31-first)
third = 356 - first - second
print first, second, third, (first + second + third)
```

It *may* be different depending on whether you allow duplicates but this answer should give you the basic approach.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're looking for the sum of a triplet, try:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> _max = 356
>>> _min = 31
>>> truemax = 356-31*3
>>> truemax
263
>>> x = randint(0,truemax)
>>> y = randint(0,truemax - x)
>>> z = truemax - x - y
>>> x,y,z = x+_min, y+_min, z+_min
>>> x,y,z
(73, 185, 98)
>>> sum([x,y,z])
356
```

Mathematically, if there is no `min`, where (356 - x - y) is a filler:

```
356 = x + y + (356 - x - y)
```

Since there is a minimum, it would be

```
356 = 31 + x + 31 + y + 31 + z
356 = 31 * 3 + x+y+z
```

So when you are generating random numbers you're effectively generating them to add up to 263 instead of 356 because of the max.

To scale the method:

```
from random import randint

def generate(numint, _min, _max):
    current_sum = 0
    truemax = _max - numint*_min
    for i in range(numint-1):
        x = randint(0,truemax - current_sum)
        current_sum+=x
        yield _min + x
    yield truemax - current_sum + _min

_list  = [i for i in generate(3, 31, 356)]
print sum(_list), _list
```

[out]:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python test.py
356 [198, 104, 54]
alvas@ubi:~$ python test.py
356 [82, 212, 62]
alvas@ubi:~$ python test.py
356 [214, 76, 66]
alvas@ubi:~$ python test.py
356 [184, 85, 87]
alvas@ubi:~$ python test.py
356 [140, 73, 143]
alvas@ubi:~$ python test.py
356 [216, 46, 94]
alvas@ubi:~$ python test.py
356 [162, 39, 155]
alvas@ubi:~$ python test.py
356 [112, 50, 194]
alvas@ubi:~$ python test.py
356 [169, 121, 66]
```